# mdadm --zero-superblock for all devices of a mdraid?

Tags: software-raid, mdadm, md

I found no way to remove a mdraid from a server with one command.

I can stop it via `mdadm --stop /dev/md0`

But the superblock is still in the devices.

`mdadm --zero-superblock DEVICE` needs every device (like /dev/sdb1)

I know that I can do `mdadm --detail /dev/md0` and then I see the devices.

I could write a fragile script to fetch the /dev/sd... strings from the output of `mdadm --detail /dev/md0`, but I would like to avoid this.

Is there a one-liner to remove the superblock from all devices of a mdraid?

I would like to avoid to parse the output of `mdadm --detail`, since this feels fragile.

Comment: I don't think so. I typically use the `--zero-superblock` on the partitions or drive by hand. Or depending on the requirement, I do `pv /dev/zero > /dev/sdXXX` to simply erase the entire drive. And then I just know which drives they were. Do you need to do this so often that a one-time manual operation does not suffice?

Comment: @Halfgaar yes, I need to do it often, so I would like to automate it. But reading the output of `mdadm --details ...` feels a bit fragile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the array component devices, you can simply issue something as

`mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sd[abcd]`

to remove the superblock from multiple devices with a single command.

Please note that `mdadm` checks for superblock before zeroing anything, so specifying `sd*` in the command above *should* only touch component disks, without writing anything to the others. However, I **strongly** suggest against doing that: any issues in the superblock detection routing, or using `--force`, are going to overwrite good data on non-component disks (causing data loss). From the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mdadm.8.html):

> If the device contains a valid md superblock, the block is overwritten
> with zeros.  With --force the block where the superblock would be is
> overwritten even if it doesn't appear to be valid.

For the reason above, if you don't know the array component devices I suggest listing them via

`blkid -t TYPE="linux_raid_member" -o device`

and then zeroing the specific disks with `mdadm --zero-superblock`. This can be scripted with a single-line bash command:

```
for dev in `blkid -t TYPE="linux_raid_member" -o device`; do echo "zeroing $dev"; mdadm --zero-superblock $dev; done
```

As always, **triple-check any such commands to avoid data loss.**

**EDIT:** to discover the array component devices without resorting to parsing of `mdadm --detail` output, you can use `lsblk`. For example, on a test array created via `loop` devices:

```
# lsblk -l -n -s /dev/md127
md127   9:127  0  255M  0 raid1
loop5   7:5    0  256M  0 loop
loop6   7:6    0  256M  0 loop
```

Comment: Thank you. Image I have two raids md0 and md1. I want to know which devices are part of md0. Up to now I found no clean way to get the devices. Parsing the output of `mdadm --detail` feels too fragile to me.

Comment: If you don't want to parse `mdadm --detail`, you can try with `lsblk -l -n -s /dev/md0`

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single command (`mdadm …`) that will remove the superblock from all devices of a mdraid. However, it's fairly straightforward to write a script that then becomes a one-liner:

```
#!/bin/bash
md=$1
[ ! -b "$md" ] && { echo "ERROR: Not a block device: $md" >&2; exit 1; }

# Collect the slices
slices=($(mdadm --detail "$md" 2>/dev/null | awk '/active/{print $NF}'))
[ ${#slices} -eq 0 ] && { echo "ERROR: No slices found for $md" >&2; exit 1; }

# Sanity check
if [ -t 2 ]
then
    echo "Active MD RAID $md has slices: ${slices[*]}" >&2
    if [ -t 0 ]
    then
        read -p 'Stop and erase (Y/n)? ' yn
        [ ! "$yn" = 'Y' ] && exit 1
    fi
fi

# Stop the array
echo "Stopping: $md" >&2
if ! mdadm --stop "$md"
then
    echo "ERROR: Cannot stop: $md" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# Erase the slices
for slice in "${slices[@]}"
do
    echo "Zero: $slice" >&2
    mdadm --zero-superblock "$slice"
done

# All done
exit 0
```

Example usage, assuming the script is called `mdzero` and it's in the PATH, etc. and the unwanted RAID device is `/dev/md1`:

```
mdzero /dev/md1

Active MD RAID /dev/md1 has slices: /dev/dm-2 /dev/dm-3 /dev/dm-4
Stop and erase (Y/n)? Y
Stopping: /dev/md1
mdadm: stopped /dev/md1
Zero: /dev/dm-2
Zero: /dev/dm-3
Zero: /dev/dm-4
```

Unless you enter a (capital) "Y" in response to the "Stop and erase?" question - or the command is being run non-interactively - the tool will quit at that point. Essentially, you've got 20+ lines of sanity checking to ensure that the active `mdadm --zero-superblock` command is only run if and where absolutely intended

Comment: thank you for the shell script. Nevertheless I would prefer a solution which gets the data in a more precise way (without `awk` from `mdadm --detail`).

Comment: @guettli I don't believe there is a better or more precise way (`mdadm` doesn't provide machine parseable output, so we have to extract the data heuristically). That's why there is an "Are you sure?" in the middle that cannot be overridden by a command-line flag. You can test the code by commenting out the `mdadm --zero-superblock`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `blkid` to do this with a little bit of manipulation.

First, get the raid array you care for.

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md0
...
UUID : 8c9c9aa9:0c574535:e9080607:7ac4c6d8
```

Convert the UUID Into a a proper UUID format and you can use `blkid` to pull out all disk members.

```
blkid -t UUID=8c9c9aa9-0c57-4535-e908-06077ac4c6d8 --output device
/dev/nvme1n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p3
```

If you just want to blast all mdadm raid arrays you dont need to collect any other identifier:

```
blkid -t TYPE="linux_raid_member" --output device
/dev/nvme1n1p2
/dev/nvme1n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p2
/dev/nvme0n1p3
```

To blast everything using this method you can even use `wipefs`. That could look something like..

```
blkid -t TYPE="linux_raid_member" --output device | xargs wipefs -n
```

Of course, this will zero all raid arrays of all disks without caring about the particular raid array in question.
I added a `-n` to prevent people being careless with their copy/paste!